# What is the difference between 9_9 and 99 as integer in Chrome console

Tags: javascript

There's a proposal of [JavaScript Numeric separators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator), which is implemented in Chrome now.

When I write `9_9 === 99` to the console, the output is `true`,
but `parseInt('9_9')` outputs `9`.

```
> parseInt("9_9")
> 9
> 9_9 === 99
> true
```

*Image of Chrome console output:*

[image: Snapshot of Chrome console].

I expect the output of `parseInt('9_9')` to be `99`, but the actual output is `9`. How do I parse numbers with separators like "9_9" to 99?

Comment: 9_9 === 99 is a syntax error.

Comment: @Teemu works fine for me in the chrome console?

Comment: Your question is unclear. this part : `I expect the output of parseInt('9_9') to be 99, but the actual output is 99.` . You expect it to be 99 but the output is .... 99. I'm not even going to try to answer a question where the OP didn't take the time and the interest to make it clear and correct.

Comment: It is a syntag error ====
"I expect the output of parseInt('9_9') to be 99, but the actual output is 99." Looks like it works correct.

Comment: @NickParsons Hmm .. "SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal" on FF console.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on latest chrome

Comment: @NickParsons `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` in Chrome

Comment: I expect the output of parseInt('9_9') to be 99, but the actual output is 99, please correct it..

Comment: It's probably worth [checking what `parseInt` actually does, not assuming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: For your `9_9====99`, quadruple `=`s are not permitted in Javascript - instead, use three (preferably)

Comment: Also: `parInt` is not a function. You should really review your question better before posting.

Comment: @Cert The extra `=` checks whether the programmer is wearing pants. Pretty handy sometimes.

Comment: @VLAZ Hmm really, I'm running `Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` of chrome... I get a syntax error in firefox but no error in Chrome

Comment: @Nick Maybe an experimental Chrome feature? There are other languages that allow you to embed `_` in numeric literals for readability. But it doesn't seem to be part of the ES spec yet: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-literals-numeric-literals

Comment: The answer to the question (once clarified and typos are fixed) almost certainly has to do with http://2ality.com/2018/02/numeric-separators.html

Comment: @NickParsons hmm, mine was behind. I updated and...you're right. Weird - why was this syntax introduced? Apparently `9_9` does indeed have the value `99`

Comment: Looks like this is it: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator

Comment: It looks like Chrome has implemented a proposed feature, only that `parseInt` implementation is not fixed along this new number format. Changing `parseInt` to support this new format is also a bit complicated, it would introduce a ton of errors in existing codebases, which (correctly)  rely on `parseInt` to return `9` from "9_9".

Comment: @Teemu I don't think `parseInt` *should* implement this. Underscores in *literals* are there to increase readability of source code. But you'll never really use `parseInt` on values hardcoded in source code, but on runtime values, and those don't require readability. And as you said, it would break existing behaviour.

Comment: @deceze I agree. How about the quetions, it turns out to be a rational question after all, should we reopen  it for a decent answer?

Comment: @Teemu If you can rewrite it to make a modicum of sense…

Comment: @Teemu the proposal doesn't mention that `parseInt` should change. And honestly, why should it? It's only taking numeric values from the front of the string, it's not "read this string as if it's a valid JS numeric literal". See, `Number` would be more interesting.

Comment: @Teemu Alright 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) has a single purpose - takes a value and *parse* the numbers out of it as an integer. So any argument given to it would be turned into string (if not already) and then the numbers extracted from there. The way it does that is to take characters from the beginning of the string until it encounters anything that cannot express an integer:

```js
//all resolve to 99
console.log(parseInt("99"));
console.log(parseInt("99 bottles on the wall"));
console.log(parseInt("99%"));
console.log(parseInt("99.87 degrees"));

//NaN because there are no numbers in the beginning
console.log(parseInt("I got 99 problems and the result here is NaN"));
```

That does *not* mean that it reads a number as if it's a valid JavaScript numeric literal. The [numeric separators proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) does not demand such a change. The [spec design](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator/blob/master/spec.md#global-object-functions-parseint-and-parsefloat) even explicitly says the following:

> ## Global object functions parseInt and parseFloat
>
> `parseFloat` semantics are unchanged. The syntax for *StrDecimalLiteral*
>   is updated to define its own *StrDecimalDigits*, preserving the behavior
>   of "parseFloat applied to the String type".
>
> `parseInt` semantics are unchanged.

So, both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are left to work as they did so far by design.

There is even precedent for their behaviour ignoring how numeric literals are treated in *code* and in *strings* with how numbers [in scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) are handled:

```js
//numeric literal for 1000 in scientific notation
console.log(1e3);

//terminates at "e" because it's not a number
console.log(parseInt("1e3"))
```

Moreover, another consideration is backwards compatibility: `parseInt` never *used to* treat `_` specially when it comes to any numbers - any application written up to now could have used `parseInt` to extract a number up to an underscore. Changing this now may mean a dramatic change in behaviour. Here is a simplistic illustrative example of what could go wrong:

```js
//a dummy function that gives the characteristics of electrical grid:
//220v and 60Hz in Europe, 110v and 50Hz in the USA
function getElectricitySpec(location) {
  if (location == "US") {
    return "110_60"
  } else if (location == "EU") {
    return "220_50";
  } 
  
  return "unknown"
}

// implementation that treats _ as part of numerics
function newParseInt(value, radix) {
  return parseInt(value.replace(/_/g, ""), radix)
}

var volts = newParseInt(getElectricitySpec("EU"));

powerComponent(volts);

function powerComponent(atVolts) {
  console.log(volts);
}
```

So, there is no reason to expect that `parseInt` should parse `99` out of `"9_9"`.